# Insert new row into table and make sure it becomes the last row

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there any way to make sure this happens? Because the table i'm working with is randomly ordering the rows as i insert new rows and i don't want that to happen. Also, i want to avoid adding a timestamp column. I've tried to search the web for answers but found nothing so far. I can only hope someone here can help me out.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to guarantee order from a database is to use an `ORDER BY` clause in your SQL when you pull it. Anything else would be a bad practice (relying on functionality that may or may not be the same from version to version or moving to another database).

Answer (score 0):

Just like records are not arrays, tables are not lists.  The relational model defines a table as an *unordered* set of records.

If you want there to be an order, you need to define what that order is and save data that determines that order accordingly.  Then, when you want your result set ordered, you need to specify the relevant ORDER BY.  That is the only way to guarantee the order of query results *by design*.

The key concept is that order is something that *the data* determine, not the database.  Order is an application rule or business rule.  If your application or business needs that rule, you need to store the data in the database to do that.  You *don't want* the database magically managing order in the background.  You don't want to be tied to an implementation detail like that.  You should be able to extract your data from your database into a text file or spreadsheet and be able to reconstruct the order.  You should be able to redetermine the order your application or business requires *even if the database changes completely*.